# Validating bash script argument by flag name and value

Tags: bash, validation, arguments

I have a bash script that I want invoked using a require `-p` argument that is of type string/alphanumeric. For example:

```
sh myscript.sh -p abc123
```

My best attempt thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
mypassword=${p:}
echo $mypassword
if [ -z mypassword ]
then
  echo "error"
fi
```

Since this is a required argument, I don't have a good meaningful default to apply (hence my attempt with using `${p:}` to set `mypassword` to empty/null, and then attempt the null check conditional right afterwards).

When I run it via `sh myscript.sh -p abc123` I get:

```
myscript.sh: line 46: ${p:}: bad substitution
```

All I'm trying to accomplish is this:

If `-p` wasn't specified, or if it was specified, but no value for it was given (e.g. `-p abc123`), I want to `echo "error"`. In other words, `-p` must not only be provided, but a value for it must be supplied as well.

**Any ideas as to how I could accomplish this?**

Comment: Use a `getopts` loop to parse the option and assign it to a variable. See ["How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash/14203146#14203146) and [BashFAQ #35: "How can I handle command-line options and arguments in my script easily?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ -z mypassword ]` will always evaluate to false, because the word *mypassword* has a length greater than zero. You could test with, for instance, `[[ -z $mypassword ]]`.

Also, the term `${p:}`  does not make sense. Perhaps you meant `${p:=}` ?

UPDATE:

One more note: The way you are invoking your script would not work, even after those fixed, becaues `mypassword` will always be empty. For your script to work, `p` must be an environment variable holding the password. You would have to call your script (assuming it is in your working directory) like this:

```
# To run it as sh-script (POSIX shell)
p=THIS_IS_MY_PASSWORD sh myscript.sh 

# To run it as bash-script, if the script is executable
p=THIS_IS_MY_PASSWORD ./myscript.sh

# To run it as bash-script, if the script is not executable
p=THIS_IS_MY_PASSWORD bash myscript.sh
```

Comment: Thanks @user1934428 (+1), just curious, why nest `-z $mypassword` inside **two** sets of braces ("`[[`" and "`]]`"), instead of just one set?

Comment: `[[` is a syntactic construct, while `[` is a command, even though bash implements it as an internal command. Íf you are only doing a `-z` and nothing else, `[[` saves you from quoting the parameter expansion, while with `[` you would have to write `[ -z "$mypassword" ]`  to catch the case where _mypassword_ contains a space.

Comment: Thanks again @user1934428 (+1), any chance you could give me a working code example that would allow me to invoke my script using the provided (desired) method? Such as `sh ./myscript.sh -p 12345`?

Comment: Gordon Davisson already did this in his comment, which also points to useful examples.  I suggest that you try to follow his advice, and if you really get stuck, ask a new question and post your approach to use `getopts`.